# Can a batch file give a command to a jar file?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

First question, be kind, I started reading about batch files 12 hours ago.

I am trying to write a batch file that will pass a command to a java jar file every 30 minutes.

I am sure this has to be possible, but my small experience with bat files just isn't cutting it.

Here is what I have written so far

```
@echo off
title Test Program

set /a count=0
start /B java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar minecraft_server.1.8.8.jar nogui
timeout /t 15 >nul
goto loop


:loop
set /a mark=30*count
set /a count=count+1
echo say Episode %count% Minute Mark %mark%
timeout /t 5  >nul

goto loop
```

For comparison, the batch file below will start and run the jar file, and if I type commands into the command prompt, the jar file responds to them.

```
title run-minecraft
java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar minecraft_server.1.8.8.jar
pause
```

For example, if I type "say hi" into the second program while it is executing, the jar file executes the "say" command and "hi" appears in the game.  The first program outputs "say Episode ..." every five seconds (I don't want to wait half an hour during testing) in the command prompt, but the say command is not executed and the desired message "Episode # Minute Mark ##" is not displayed in the game.

I think that the problem is that I am not telling the command prompt to execute the code that the batch file is writing into it, but I am not sure how to make that happen automatically.

Sorry if this is confusing because I am not using the proper terms, but I am not a programmer and do not know better.

Comment: On a side comment, do yourself a favor and learn to use powershell instead of batch. It is much more modern and supported since Vista

Comment: This is not a batch file problem.  The Java program needs to be able to accept command line arguments.

Comment: @Squashman I believe he's talking about stdin rather than command-line arguments

Answer (score 0):

In your short batch file, the solution works because the Java command is opened in another command line in which the I/O are plugged in the Java application.
In your new batch, using start /b you open the Java application without a command-line and therefore without an I/O.
I'm not well-versed enough in batch to answer your question but what you need is to find how to redirect commands I/O, that is have control over the input (and possibly output, but it's irrelevant here) of the Java command.

Looks like [this](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) is a good start.

Comment: @aschipfl must be on your side, I checked it and it works for me. Another ressource for those who would have your problem : https://jpsoft.com/help/redirection.htm

Comment: I encountered the problem on two sites... anyway, thanks for the alternative link...